# Different coloring schemes for nodes of the same type

Tags: neo4j

I'm contemplating doing some graph visualization with Neo4j.  I watched a few of the visualization videos, and saw that by using the Neo4j browser that one is able to easily color nodes and relationship.  What I did not see was if one is able to color nodes of the same type differently based on properties, ie:

Node Person {
      Age
}

If Person.Age in range(12-18) color blue, 19-25: black, etc.

If so, could someone please give me a basic explanation as to how to go about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now it's not possible,

perhaps you want to check out [d3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) directly or libraries built on top like [Alchemy.js](http://graphalchemist.github.io/Alchemy/#/examples#Custom_Styling)

Answer (score 2):

Currently the Neo4j browser does not allow to color the nodes according to a given property. If you want to achieve that kind of effect you can use a graph visualization library (like [D3.js](http://d3js.org) or [Sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/)).

If you do not want to build the feature on your own, [Linkurious](http://linkurio.us) provides the ability to color the nodes of a Neo4use a graph visualization tool

Jean, Co-Founder of Linkurious